# How to install sshfs on Raspberry Pi OpenElec

Tags: linux, sshfs

I just got a Raspberry Pi with OpenElec and want to access shared files using sshfs.

I tried compiling the sshfs source on OpenElec but the command make is not installed.

**How can I install sshfs on OpenElec?**

Comment: You could try an addon with sshfs... possibly https://github.com/OpenELEC/unofficial-addons/tree/master/addons/tools/sshfs-fuse would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the instruction from the link at the readme from the repo. If it helps anybody this are the instructions: [link] (http://unofficial.addon.pro). So far everything seems to work!

Comment: Great! If you could write up an answer and then accept it for yourself (possibly after a three day waiting period) it would be helpful for others facing the same issue.